# How to compare points in space?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Say I have many points $(x, y)$ points on a 2d coordinate system. Some points are coloured blue, other points are coloured red.

The coordinate system has 4 quadrants (see image below). For this particular problem, large $x$ and small $y$ is "better", so the best quadrant is the upper left quadrant, and the worst is the lower right quadrant.

What possible metrics are there to figure out which points are "better", the red ones or the blue ones?

I was thinking of just using $x/y$ as my metric and then averaging. So the average $x/y$ for the red and blue points tells me which one is better. But are there better ones than this?

[Quadrants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6glEf.png)

Comment: So you said that "For this particular problem, large x and small y is better" ... Would you have any context for this? How was this determined?

Comment: Another idea: Would $y-x$ work as a metric?

Comment: I don't get the implication in the second paragraph about which are the best quadrants.

Comment: Upper left quadrant = high x, low y. So it's better. What is there not to get?

Comment: So the point (-1, 20) in the upper left quadrant has high x, low y?

Comment: $x$ is on the vertical axis on my plots.

Comment: But not in the image you posted?